# How do I connect to the internet with a "Huwaei Ec1260" modem?

Tags: network-manager, modem

I have a Reliance netconnect Huwaei Ec1260 modem . How can I use this to connect  to the internet?

Answer (score 3):

- For Ubuntu 10.04 (skip this step for Ubuntu 10.10): install [usb-modeswitch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/usb-modeswitch)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
  ```
- Right Click on the NetworkManager icon from the panel notification area > **Edit Connections**.

[image]

- Mobile Broadband > Add.

[image]

You will get a New Mobile Broadband Connection Dialog. (Reliance-Huawei is autodetected)

[image]

- Forward > Country List: **India**

[image]

- Forward > Choose your Provider: **Reliance**

[image]

- Enter the username and password (provided by your network provider: Reliance).

[image]

- Apply.
- Click on the NetworkManager icon and select the Mobile Broadband connection.

Comment: still got nothing happen,
I am using CSL U2-TF modem

Comment: @ok comp: This method works for modems that are supported out-of-the-box by Ubuntu. (Huawei modems are generally well supported.)

Comment: @ok comp I am confused, this answer is for a huwaei ec1260, not a csl u2-tf.

Comment: i have already done the same but it just start connecting and then after some time it display an error that it cannot connect to the network

Comment: @FOSS DIVERSER: This method works for me. When you get a connection error, restart the nm-applet by doing this: 1. Alt+F2 and enter this: pkill nm-applet 2. Alt+F2 and enter this: nm-applet