# How to use Huawei K3765 under Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, modem, 3g, huawei

Before and after plugging in the 3G modem:

```
root@MACHINE:~# ls /dev/ttyUSB*
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB*: No such file or directory
root@MACHINE:~#
```

Logs:

```
root@MACHINE:~# tail -f /var/log/messages
Nov  9 11:43:37 localhost kernel: [423418.057015] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 99
Nov  9 11:43:38 localhost kernel: [423418.191322] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:43:38 localhost kernel: [423418.196033] scsi121 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:38 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:43:38 localhost kernel: [423418.706980] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 99
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423422.941015] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 100
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.074346] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.076801] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.076889] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.077042] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.077095] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.077157] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.077209] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.085767] scsi122 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:42 localhost kernel: [423423.088685] scsi123 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:43 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122630] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122651] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122720] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122743] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122812] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:43:48 localhost kernel: [423429.122829] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:43:49 localhost kernel: [423429.236063] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 100
Nov  9 11:43:52 localhost kernel: [423432.976035] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 101
Nov  9 11:43:52 localhost kernel: [423433.111196] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:43:52 localhost kernel: [423433.112234] scsi124 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:53 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:43:53 localhost kernel: [423433.626977] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 101
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423437.977017] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 102
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.111340] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.113796] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.113885] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114029] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114084] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114148] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114200] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114528] scsi125 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:57 localhost kernel: [423438.114763] scsi126 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:43:58 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116264] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116287] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116373] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116393] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116466] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:03 localhost kernel: [423444.116490] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:04 localhost kernel: [423444.229033] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 102
Nov  9 11:44:07 localhost kernel: [423447.940014] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 103
Nov  9 11:44:07 localhost kernel: [423448.076410] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:07 localhost kernel: [423448.077432] scsi127 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:08 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:08 localhost kernel: [423448.592693] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 103
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423452.932013] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 104
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.066182] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.068633] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.068723] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.068866] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.068920] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.068982] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.069046] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.086987] scsi128 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:12 localhost kernel: [423453.097383] scsi129 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:13 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520090] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520112] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520184] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520210] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520278] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.520295] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:19 localhost kernel: [423459.633030] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 104
Nov  9 11:44:23 localhost kernel: [423463.978147] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 105
Nov  9 11:44:23 localhost kernel: [423464.111465] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:23 localhost kernel: [423464.114922] scsi130 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:24 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:24 localhost kernel: [423464.629736] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 105
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423468.969014] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 106
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.103236] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.105684] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.105769] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.105913] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.105970] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.106231] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.106288] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.106462] scsi131 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:28 localhost kernel: [423469.106706] scsi132 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:29 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735012] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735033] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735105] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735133] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735201] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.735219] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:35 localhost kernel: [423475.848029] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 106
Nov  9 11:44:39 localhost kernel: [423479.932153] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 107
Nov  9 11:44:39 localhost kernel: [423480.066396] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:39 localhost kernel: [423480.067423] scsi133 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:40 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:40 localhost kernel: [423480.583557] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 107
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423484.924147] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 108
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.059297] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.061750] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.061838] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.061980] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.062035] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.062100] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.062160] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.067591] scsi134 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:44 localhost kernel: [423485.081538] scsi135 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:45 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814586] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814602] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814680] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814708] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814778] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.814797] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:44:50 localhost kernel: [423490.929038] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 108
Nov  9 11:44:54 localhost kernel: [423494.964149] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 109
Nov  9 11:44:54 localhost kernel: [423495.098227] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:54 localhost kernel: [423495.099271] scsi136 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:55 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:44:55 localhost kernel: [423495.614634] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 109
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423499.956044] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 110
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.090998] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093453] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093543] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093690] option 1-2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093746] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093809] option 1-2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.093862] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.095971] scsi137 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:44:59 localhost kernel: [423500.110667] scsi138 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:45:00 localhost usb-modeswitch: switched to 12d1:1465 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.193916] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.193938] option 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.194010] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.194038] option 1-2:1.2: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.194109] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.194126] option 1-2:1.3: device disconnected
Nov  9 11:45:06 localhost kernel: [423506.309029] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 110
Nov  9 11:45:09 localhost kernel: [423509.933015] usb 1-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 111
Nov  9 11:45:09 localhost kernel: [423510.067119] usb 1-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  9 11:45:09 localhost kernel: [423510.068160] scsi139 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Nov  9 11:45:10 localhost usb-modeswitch: switching 12d1:1520 (HUAWEI Technology: HUAWEI Mobile)
Nov  9 11:45:10 localhost kernel: [423510.583529] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, address 111
^C
root@MACHINE:~#
```

The problematic 3G modem is a K3765.

How to bring it to life?
lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 12d1:1465 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I hope this link help you, is in Spanish.
https://blog.insac.net/ubuntu-16-04-lamp-gammu/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you're having is because the Huawei K3765 uses USB "mode-switching" to tell the dongle to stop being a CD drive (where the windows drivers are) and to just be a 3G modem.

If I'm right, just install the usb modeswitching program and it should work automatically:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

Now unplug the modem and plug it back in.

If that works, the linux kernel has the basics to work with your modem.

Follow the steps in [How do I connect to the internet with a "Huwaei Ec1260" modem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15137/how-do-i-connect-to-the-internet-with-a-huwaei-ec1260-modem) to get things set up.

For more info on USB mode-switching and why it's needed, take a look at     http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

Enjoy

Comment: ty! I updated the problem/question.. :\

Comment: Updated the response.  Not 100% because the logs already mention mode-switching but give it a shot.

Comment: I found that the: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/device_reference.txt file contains the K3765! I'm just wondering how to bring it to life, I already tried this: https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=12 but the gui app doesn't shows the 3g modem

Comment: I will try this...hopefully it will help: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gfzi4EKp - I will post it here if it helped! ty!